# Create view to show all documents, child documents, and subfolders?

Tags: 2007, document-library, list-view

Is there a way in Sharepoint OOTB to show all the documents and folders in **and** below a folder or Document library?

For example, If I have the following structure:

```
- http://site/Document Library/File.ext 
- http://site/Document Library/Folder1/File1.ext
- http://site/Document Library/Folder1/Folder2/File2.ext
```

When on the following page: `http://site/Document Library/Folder/`

I get the following items in my view:

- Folder2
- File1.ext
- File2.ext

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to go under Folders section in your view, and in the Folder or Flat radio-buttons choosed the option "Show all items without folders"

Comment: I also want the folders displayed. This show all items without folders ONLY shows files but I want a flat view with folders and files.

Comment: No can do with out-of-the-box Views. In other pages you could use SPD to build you a view, but not easy with no-code solution (CAML Query skills required).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit redundant, but you could create a column to hold the name of the folder and group on that column in a flat view. This would give you the folder view you need while giving you the ability to expand and collapse those folders as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the SPViewScope in C#:

```
SPView view = list.Views["YourViewName"];
view.Scope = SPViewScope.RecursiveAll; //more ViewScopes are available
view.Update()
```